# Как правильно написать SQL запрос, где во WHERE должен использоваться IF?

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. Есть таблица products, где есть столбцы price(обычная цена товара) ,sale_price(распродажа, по умолчанию NULL) и is_discount(0 или 1). Задача: выбрать все строки, где цена на товар начинается с 4000. Сделал следующее:

`SELECT * FROM products as p WHERE p.price >= $price OR p.sale_price >= $price`

(ЗЫ в проекте, естественно, используется PDO, это всего лишь пример, отображающий полную суть вопроса)

К примеру, есть товар, у которого Обычная стоимость 4999, а по распродаже 3999. Проблема в том, что в запросе используется OR, поэтому при `$price = 4000` попадет в список, чего быть не должно, поскольку по скидке его цена 3999. Вопрос: каким образом выбрать все товары, где текущая цена будет больше или равна 4000? Т.е. по логике, тут должен быть логический оператор: если `is_discount = 1`, то ищем по `sale_price`, иначе по `price`. Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: `IF(p.is_discount, p.sale_price, p.price) >= $price`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM products as p
WHERE (p.is_discount = 0 AND p.price >= $price)
   OR (p.is_discount = 1 AND p.sale_price >= $price)
```

или

```
SELECT *
FROM products as p
WHERE p.is_discount = 0 AND p.price >= $price
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM products as p
WHERE p.is_discount = 1 AND p.sale_price >= $price
```

или

```
SELECT *
FROM products as p
WHERE CASE WHEN p.is_discount = 0
        THEN p.price
        ELSE p.sale_price
      END >= $price
```

PS в последнем варианте я не уверен - надо проверить...

Comment: Спасибо большое! Подскажите, пожалуйста. У меня уже есть одно условие where: `WHERE p.category_parent_id = :parent_id`. Если добавить туда первый вариант, получится вот так: `AND (p.is_sale = 0 AND p.price >= 4000) OR (p.is_discount = 1 AND p.sale_price >= 4000)`, но это неправильно. Как связать данное условие с еще одним через AND?

Comment: А, нет, все правильно, просто добавил еще одни скобки.